# Unable to parse Json response from MongoDB hosted on mLAB

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, api, mlab

I have a document say cars hosted on mLAB. When I do the GET request for cars using the mLAB API, I receive the following response :

```
>     [ { "_id" : { "$oid" : "5a5e381c734d1d347184ed9d"} , "car_ID" : "1122" , "car_location_latitude" : "14.764976" ,
> "car_location_longitude" : "13.543345" , "s1" : "" , "s2" : "" , "s3"
> : "966" , "s4" : "" , "s5" : "" , "m1" : "" , "m2" : "" , "m3" : "" ,
> "l1" : "" , "l2" : ""} , { "_id" : { "$oid" :
> "5a5e383a734d1d347184edb4"} , "car_ID" : "1234" ,
> "car_location_latitude" : "12.975715" , "car_location_longitude" :
> "77.572836" , "s1" : "" , "s2" : "" , "s3" : "" , "s4" : "" , "s5" :
> "" , "m1" : "567" , "m2" : "" , "m3" : "" , "l1" : "" , "l2" : ""} ]
```

NodeJS Code : Piece of code from where I am making the API calls to mLAB.

```
Display Requests
app.get('/..../requests',function(req,res){

    var id=req.params.deliveryID;
    var result="";
    function second()
    {
    return res.status(200).send('{ \"data\":{\"type":\"text\",\"text\":\"'+result+'\"}}');
    }

    function first(callback)
    {

    request('https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/.................', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) 
    {

        console.log("---->"+body+"-----");
        result=body;
        var o=JSON.parse(body);

        //Now using variable o, how can I access JSON Keys car_ID etc

        callback(second);
    }
    });

    }
    first(second);


});
```

Comment: ok, what is the issue?

Comment: from object o of Json.parse , How can I get the value associated with key say car_ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` returns cars is an array of object, you can simply iterate the objects and access its elements

cars array response

```
var cars = [
        { "_id" : "5a5e381c734d1d347184ed9d" , "car_ID" : "1122" , "car_location_latitude" : "14.764976" ,            "car_location_longitude" : "13.543345" , "s1" : "" , "s2" : "" , "s3"            : "966" , "s4" : "" , "s5" : "" , "m1" : "" , "m2" : "" , "m3" : "" ,            "l1" : "" , "l2" : ""        } , 
        { "_id" : "5a5e383a734d1d347184edb4" , "car_ID" : "1234" , "car_location_latitude" : "12.975715" , "car_location_longitude" : "77.572836" , "s1" : "" , "s2" : "" , "s3" : "" , "s4" : "" , "s5" : "" , "m1" : "567" , "m2" : "" , "m3" : "" , "l1" : "" , "l2" : ""
 } 
 ]
```

iterator

```
for (var car of cars){
    console.log(car.car_ID)
}
```

output

```
saravana@ubuntu:~/node-mongoose$ node so5.js
1122
1234
saravana@ubuntu:~/node-mongoose$
```

If the response is an json array of string then you many need to parse and iterate

```
var carsArray = JSON.parse(body);
for (var i = 0; i < carsArray.length; i++){
    var car = carsArray[i];
    console.log(car.car_ID)
}
```